# Can I store Assets on a Cloud Service like Amazon S3?

Tags: craft3, plugins

Is there any way to store Assets on a Cloud Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could install the Amazon S3 Plugin in order to select & configure that Volume type in your control panel.

After installing that you will get new volume type “Amazon S3” in Settings → Assets → New Volume.

Now you can create new column and using it you can store your assets in Amazon S3 cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @ZealousWeb said, if you want to make life especially simple, you can store all your S3 credentials and information in your .env file. If you want much more detail on this (including the best settings for your S3 bucket and the easiest way to connect Cloudfront so you're not serving assets directly from S3), I highly recommend [Andrew Welch's article](https://nystudio107.com/blog/using-aws-s3-buckets-cloudfront-distribution-with-craft-cms) on the matter.